# Use of "in this light"

Tags: word-choice, idioms

In my language there is an idiom *in this light* which roughly means *from this perspective* or *in connection with this*. Can I use this idiom in English? For example,

> This presidential candidate was often accused of corruption, in this
>   light his anti-corruption speech looked as a nonsense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the idiom also exists in English. We'd use it as the start of another sentence (I've corrected small errors here).

> The presidential candidate was often accused of corruption. In this light, his anti-corruption speech seems nonsensical.

You can also reference the aspect which causes the light.

> In light of recent accusations, I have decided to step down as a candidate.

Even further, you can reference shadows (though we wouldn't say "In this shadow").

> His candidacy, coming as it did in the shadow of multiple accusations of corruption, was never promising.

Comment: Thanks. I just wonder why you omitted the article from "In light of recent accusations".

Comment: No idea. It's been idiomatic since 1680 though, so if you find someone very old maybe they can tell you: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=light

Comment: The other answer claims that an article is needed here. Who is correct?

Comment: If in doubt, check NGrams: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+light+of+this%2C+in+light+of+this%2C+in+this+light

Comment: For the metaphor (of illumination), without the article, 'in light of', is what you want. -With- the article, it is still grammatical but it sounds literal like actual light is shining.

Answer (score 1):

"In this light" need not only be used to start a sentence.  For example,

"I feel that I am an excellent candidate for the promotion, and hope that the efforts that I have made in the past year will be seen in this light."

Here "will be seen in this light" is equivalent to "will be considered accordingly".